# Downloading a file (or handling an HTTP error) on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on my page that, when clicked, will try to go out and download a file from a given URL on a *different* domain than my page's domain.  Sometimes, that download URL will return an HTTP 429 response with an error message as content.  I am trying to be able to handle both cases (successful download vs error).

Here is my code:

```
var w = window.open(url);
window.focus();
w.onload = function() {
  console.log(w.document.body.innerHTML);
};
```

The above code is run on a button click.  What I'm seeing is that the `w.onload` function is never getting triggered.  What is wrong with using this as a method of downloading a file?

Comment: _"What is wrong with using this as a method of downloading a file?"_ : _"will try to go out and download a file from a given URL on a different domain"_

Comment: If url is a different domain, you are not going to have access to its DOM

Comment: Right, I see your comments and I agree.  I have noted that this is not working - I am asking about alternatives.  I need to either download the file or handle a 429

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()`, with `error` event attached to request resource. If request is not successful, error should be handled at `error` event handler of `XMLHttpRequest()`.

You could alternatively use `fetch()` to achieve same result.

Set `.responseType` to `"blob"` at `XMLHttpRequest` or return `response.blob()` at `fetch()`. Create a new `Blob` with `type` set to `"application/octet-stream"`, call `window.open()` with `URL.createObjectURL()` as parameter where `Blob` is parameter to `.createObjectURL()`, which should open `Save File` dialog.

You can chain `.catch()` to `fetch()` to handle errors.

```
<body>
  <a href="#" data-link="file.txt">download file.txt</a>
  <a href="#" data-link="http://stackoverflow.com">download stackoverflow.com</a>
  <script>

    var request = (path) =>
      fetch(path)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => window.open(
        URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([blob], {
            type: "application/octet-stream"
          })
        ), "_self"))
      // handle request error
      .catch((err) => {console.log(err); throw err});

    var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    for (let link of a) {
      link.onclick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        request(e.target.dataset.link)
        .catch((err) => {
          alert(err.message + "\ndownload of " + e.target.dataset.link + " error")
        })
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/J40cPoLJ2WwESRzsSRhL?p=preview

---

Alternatively using `<a>` element, `download` attribute to suggest file name at `Save File` dialog

```
<body>
  <a href="#" data-link="file.txt">download file.txt</a>
  <a href="#" data-link="http://stackoverflow.com">download stackoverflow.com</a>
  <script>

    var request = (path) =>
      fetch(path)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        var type = blob.type.split("/").pop();
        type = type === "plain" ? "txt" : type;
        var d = document.createElement("a");
        d.className = "download";
        d.download = "file-" + new Date().getTime() + "." + type;
        d.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        d.click();
        d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
      })
      // handle request error
      .catch((err) => {console.log(err); throw err});

    var a = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#']");
    for (let link of a) {
      link.onclick = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        e.preventDefault();
        request(e.target.dataset.link)
        .catch((err) => {
          alert(err.message + "\ndownload of " + e.target.dataset.link + " error")
        })
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is interesting...makes a lot of sense.  How do you keep the file type though?  Creating a blob, you would lose that file type entirely.  Let's say it's an mp4 video file, how do you detect that and rebuild it as the right file type?

Comment: @Jim _"How do you keep the file type though? Creating a blob, you would lose that file type entirely. Let's say it's an mp4 video file, how do you detect that and rebuild it as the right file type?"_  The file type would not be lost. You can use `<a>` element, `download` attribute, if available at browser, to set file name including extension of originally returned `Blob` of `response`. Though note, user could change suggested file name or extension at `Save File` dialog

Comment: @Jim See version 3 at http://plnkr.co/edit/J40cPoLJ2WwESRzsSRhL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

For handling the download of the file, the [download](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) attribute could be a solution (with [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652750/any-fallback-client-side-solutions-for-the-html5-download-attribute)).

But for the handling the HTTP errors in my opinion the best solution is using some back-end proxy which will check the HTTP headers and also [will force the browser to download a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180690/how-to-force-download-different-type-of-extension-file-php).